# How to set the visibility to be "GONE" for a view which is a FooterView of a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I add a `FooterView` in a `ListView`, But when i set the view's visibility to be `GONE`, just the content of the view is hided. I means it leaves space in the `ListView`, just like the `INVISIBLE`.
How can I set the `FooterView` to be `GONE`.

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: I think you should user listView.removefooterView  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#removeFooterView%28android.view.View%29

Comment: I have got a method, when i set the height of childView's layoutParams to 0, it working OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the footer like this:

```
listView.removeFooterView(view);
```

Comment: That wouldn't help for two reasons: firstly, headers and footers are supposed to be added *before* you set the adapter (so the view can wrap the adapter cursor with the header and footer views) and secondly, if you have multiple headers or footers and you wanted to add one back, it would be put on the end of the list, not in its original position.